# Dot product with numpy gives array with size (n, )

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to get the dotproduct of two arrays in python using the numpy package. I get as output an array of size (n,). It says that my array has no column while I do see the results when I print it. Why does my array have no column and how do I fix this?
My goal is to calculate `y - np.dot(x,b)`. The issue is that y is (124, 1) while np.dot(x,b) is (124,)
Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In this case, pasting the code that you ran to get this result is probably sufficient.

Comment: probably due to your array being 1-dimensional, but as Ben said, within more information hard to say

Comment: What happens when you try dotting `y[:,0]` instead of just `y`? If that doesn't work, try adding an axis on the `dot(x,b)` quantity like `result = np.dot(x,b); result=result[:,None]; print(y-result)`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to subtract two arrays of a different shape. Fortunately, it is off by a single additional axis, so there are two ways of handling it.

(1) You slice the `y` array to match the shape of the `dot(x,b)` array:

```
y = y[:,0]
print(y-np.dot(x,b))
```

(2) You add an additional axis on the `np.dot(x,b)` array:

```
dot = np.dot(x,b)
dot = dot[:,None]
print(y-dot)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Small addition to option (2), I think it is better to just add a new axis without adding arbitrary values. So, consider using `y-dot[:, np.newaxis]`

Answer (score 0):

it may depends on the dimension of your array

For example :

```
a = [1, 0]
b = [[4, 1], [2, 2]]
c = np.dot(a,b)
```

gives

> array([4, 1])

and its shape is (2,)

but if you change a like :

```
a = [[1, 0],[1,1]]
```

then result is :

> array([[4, 1],
> [6, 3]])

and its shape is (2,2)